# Php url rewrite and redirect in htacess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect my site to friendly.
I have my website pull data from database and adress is /post?id=1
and i want to change it to /post/1
I already wrote the code for  rewrite but i cant make sense from google research how to redirect to /post/1.

***my code***

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Problem is i want to redirect id=1 to post/1
I already rewrote it i just want to redirect it too.

Comment: Croises's answer should work.

Comment: Yes it's perfect :D i Voted him up :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+post\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: God bless you. Can i ask you where did you learn what each of this things mean? :D

Comment: All on this site ;-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ post.php?id=$1  [NC]
```

if you goto url  /post/check1/

the htaccess file internally call post?id=check1

Comment: I want that in reverse if i call post?id=check1
to get  /post/check1/